# Retain scroll position in infinite RecycleView inside ScrollView (ANDROID)

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have RecycleView inside the ScrollView that can infinite scroll and always load new data with paging. Is there any way to save my scroll position (RecycleView and ScrollView) when Activity get onPause(), and restore when onResume().
Just like Instagram, Facebook, etc. when we click for detail posting and back to the timeline exactly in the same position when we left before`enter code here`.

Comment: I confused with save and restore the ScrollView position or RecycleView position, or both of them.

Answer (score 1):

My advice : use RecycleView inside another RecycleView. So for RecycleView you can use this strategy :  1) Save last visible item position 2) Do some manipulations 3) Restore your position

```
int lastViewedPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)rv.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();

//some manipulations 

rv.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(lastViewedPosition + data.size() - 1);
```

Comment: I would suggest using smoothScrollToPosition() instead of scrollToPosition().  It's a bit less jarring to the user that way.

Comment: My UI is different, cannot implement full RecycleView. Not whole repeat child layout like RecycleView do.